# How to get specific nodes from a Json Tree without iterating through the entire list

Tags: java, json, jackson, nodes

Consider the following Json structure:

```
{ "ubds": [
  {
    "id": "33",
    "metaData": {
      "lineInfo": {
        "poNumber": "PO_123",
        "poLineNumber": 1
      }
    },
    "confirmedDeliveryDate": "2016-05-26T16:15:51",
    "quantity": 99
  },
  {
    "id": "34",
    "metaData": {
      "lineInfo": {
        "poNumber": "PO_123",
        "poLineNumber": 2
      }
    },
    "confirmedDeliveryDate": "2016-05-26T16:15:51",
    "quantity": 99
  },
  {
    "id": "35",
    "metaData": {
      "lineInfo": {
        "poNumber": "PO_123",
        "poLineNumber": 3
      }
    },
    "confirmedDeliveryDate": "2016-05-26T16:15:51",
    "quantity": 99
  }]}
```

Using JsonNode, is there a way to get the entire child node {id through quantity} with the poLineNumber attribute value of 3 without having to iterate through all the nodes and returning on a match? Do I need to use JsonPath for this?

Comment: without iteration how u will find the "poLineNumber": 3

Comment: As i searched the internet, I couldn't find a method other than iterating the whole array. I think, there's no other way.

Comment: Gayathri, assume I have the poLineNumber values and simply want to extract the record, almost like if I had a list of keys for a given Map and wanted to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).
You can first use `ObjectMapper` to create a `Map<String, Object>` from the given json string, and read it and evaluate a JsonPath expression. For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> mappedObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);

// Evaluate that expression
Object result = JsonPath.read(mappedObject, "$.ubds[?(@.metaData.lineInfo.poLineNumber==3)]");
```

or directly read the json string with `JsonPath`:

```
Object result = JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read("$.ubds[?(@.metaData.lineInfo.poLineNumber==3)]");
```

Comment: JsonPath was the way to go. Thanks!